# Trying to get property of non-object, can't access to phoneNumber properties

Tags: php, laravel-5, table-relationships

```
Route::get('/', function (){

$contacts = Contact::all();
//dd($contacts);

return view('welcome')->with('contacts',$contacts);

});
```

From the route i pass the $cotacts to the view

```
@foreach($contacts as  $contact)

    <li> {{$contact->name}}

        <small>by {{$contact->phoneNumber->number}}</small>

    </li>

@endforeach
```

but when i what to access the number of  phoneNumber, this is my class:

```
public function phoneNumber()
    {
         return $this->hasOne(PhoneNumber::class);
    }
```

i get error **Trying to get property of non-object** ???

also when i put like this:

```
<li> {{$contact->name}}

            <small>by {{$contact->phoneNumber}}</small>

        </li>
```

i get:
Colton Kilback IV by `{"id":20,"contact_id":1,"number":"+1-936-288-3493","created_at":"2018-04-01 20:14:16","updated_at":"2018-04-01 20:14:16"}`

Shaun Streich DVM by

Dr. Ruthe Thiel III by

Laverne Mertz by `{"id":11,"contact_id":4,"number":"(769) 844-4643 x59321","created_at":"2018-04-01 20:14:16","updated_at":"2018-04-01 20:14:16"}`

and so on some name don't have number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have an associated `PhoneNumber` for your `Contacts` with the names `Dr. Ruthe Thiel III` and `Shaun Streich DVM`.

You can use this in your blade template instead:

```
<li> {{$contact->name}}
    <small>by {{$contact->phoneNumber->number ?? ''}}</small>
</li>
```

which will simply ommit the phone number if none is available.

---

**Edit:** if you want the output to be a bit more nice, you can also use something like this:

```
<li> {{$contact->name}}
    @if(count($contact->phoneNumber))
        <small>by {{$contact->phoneNumber->number}}</small>
    @else
        <small>has no known phone number</small>
    @endif
</li>
```

Comment: when i try second i get same error Trying to get property of non-object, and  first solution phpstorm is teling me on ?? that Coalece operator is available in PHP7 only and traits can be used only in PHP 5.4 but when i check version i have PHP 7.1.9

Comment: Not sure about the error with your PHP version, but I updated the snippet. I think with the eager loading, `isset()` doesn't work - but `count()` should always work.